# Using a custom .bst in Overleaf

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, overleaf

I'm trying to use a custom .bst in Overleaf for my thesis (specifically [ACM-Reference-Format.bst](https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart/blob/primary/ACM-Reference-Format.bst)), but I haven't found out any guides to do it on Overleaf. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Just upload the `.bst` file to your project and it should be found.

Comment: Generally just uploading the bst to the project should make it discoverable as @AlanMunn mentioned. However, depending on how you are coding your thesis, the bib and its style might be set up in to your cls file or  in a sty file associated with the thesis "template." If you are stuck and can't figure out how the bibliography is working for this template, please get in touch with Overleaf support: https://www.overleaf.com/contact

Comment: Overleaf-specific questions should be sent to the Overleaf Helpdesk. Their LaTeX support staff are top notch.